# Python another option to tkinter label counter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that I'm currently using tkinter to pop up a window and use the root.title of the window as a counter.  I call this program through subprocess mutliple times, aka multiple windows pop up and display that I only have to look at the counter to see how long before each of the programs is finished running.

I want to know how long before each and every process is finished.  Doing a bit of testing I don't believe using subprocess it will report back to IDLE and show a counter using print(). At least it doesn't appear to be doing so right now for me.

Is there any way of accomplishing this same task without using tkinter?

Below is the link to the other open question right now that I'm currently using to open the tkinter window that closes on me unexpectedly.  I'm not completely sure when a windows closes if the whole program stops running or if just the windows closes.  Hence why I want the counter...hence why I have always been using a tkinter window as I don't know of any other way of doing this that serves the same purpose.

I want the counter so I can tell the program was finished if my internet connection gets dropped.  I don't have internet access at home so I'm always using free-wifi which quite often has timeouts on it.  I want to know for sure whether the programs have finished running or if I got timedout and need to rerun the program.

[Python program terminating unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110504/python-program-terminating-unexpectedly)

Comment: Please provide some code examples and where you currently stand so we can help you debug. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added the link the the other open question I have on the same topic just not realizing when I asked the question that it could simply be tkinter shutting down.  If I could avoid tkinter shutting down but still have the counter then the mission is accomplished...at least I think it is until I get the full chance to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: "I want to know for sure whether the programs have finished running or if I got timedout and need to rerun the program.": Create a new variable; if task gets done, assign a new value to this variable, else assign another value.

Comment: I think you actually have two questions in the above question: first, you want to get the process time for every process; and you want to make sure whether your program got shut down intentionally or unintentionally.

Comment: For the first question you can use `time` module to get process time; and for the second question, I already gave an answer. If I have not got wrong, you need to get a status of your program. Thus you can use a variable to handle this issue. But I'm not sure if these are really what you are looking for...

Comment: Not really looking for the time, just knowing how far along the program is with running the code gives me a bit of idea, depending on internet connection speed if the code will finish running on time before the internet connection gets reset.  So what I really want is something visible that I can see how far along the program is.  How can I display an updated counter on one line other than using something like tkinter title.  Given that this process above is called multiple times hence multiple tkinter windows that get opened up each displaying the title counter.